# Kubernetes dashboard is not coming

Tags: kubernetes

I have created the kubernetes cluster on Google container engine and I am not able to open dashboard.
Command line if I run command all are working.

Can you please help me?
I am getting below message on browser:

```
kind    "Status"
apiVersion  "v1"
metadata    {}
status  "Failure"
message "no endpoints available for service \"kubernetes-dashboard\""
reason  "ServiceUnavailable"
code    503

User "system:anonymous" cannot get services/proxy in the namespace "kube-system".: "No policy matched.\nUnknown user \"system:anonymous\""
```

Comment: did you try with "kubectl proxy" command. then hit http://localhost:8001/ui.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an RBAC issue, as illustrated in [issue 39722](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/39722), and documented in [PR 2618](https://github.com/kubernetes/website/pull/2618/files) and [PR 2169](https://github.com/kubernetes/website/pull/2169/files).

Check if your installation went well, not like [issue 2415](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/issues/2415):  Only cluster admin can deploy Dashboard. The same issue illustrates a [successful dashboard deployment](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/issues/2415#issuecomment-348370032).
See also [this FAQ entry](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/wiki/FAQ#i-am-using-kubernetes-gce-cluster-but-getting-forbidden-access-errors).